# How can I avoid an 1100 error using MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, email

I'm trying to send an email from with my Swift app. Nothing fancy. Subject. Body. Recipients. I'm doing this like the examples I've seen which is to say NOT using a separate view controller - just a basic vc but specifying MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate like so:

`class MyVC: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

I then have the two methods I see in all the examples:

```
@IBAction func sendEmail()
{
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setSubject(subject)
        mail.setToRecipients(recipients)
        mail.setMessageBody(content, isHTML: true)
            
        present(mail, animated: true)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
}
    
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
{
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

But when the email gets cancelled (Delete Draft) I get:

```
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver'
```

No crashing. Emails get sent just fine. But I noticed that the cancelled emails pile up in Mail. The drafts are not being deleted. What am I missing? Does anyone have this kind of thing working?

Comment: The `AXRuntimeCommon` log statement is irrelevant. Yes, drafts aren't deleted, that's by design. There's no error in your code, everything is working as expected.

Comment: However you should consider not everyone uses Apple Mail, and the `MFMailComposeViewController` only works when Apple Mail is configured. So anyone using GMail/Outlook won't get the compose view, it'll just silently fail. You can check for this with `canSendMail()`